# Nova route overwriting

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-nova

Nova 3 and Laravel 8

In **RouteServiceProvider** I added

```php
   Route::prefix('nova-api')
       ->middleware(['nova'])
       ->domain(config('nova.domain'))
       ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Nova')
       ->group(base_path('routes/nova-api.php'));
```

And the file content is

```php
Route::delete('/{resource}/{resourceId}/field/{field}', 'FieldDestroyController@handle');
Route::delete('/testing', 'FieldDestroyController@handle');
```

After restarting project I see testing route, but not nova overwritten.
Is it possible to overwrite routes and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution that works!**

Create new ServiceProvider

```
php artisan make:provider NovaServiceProvider (or php artisan make:provider NovaRouteServiceProvider)
```

And place overwrite code .
In my case it is

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Laravel\Nova\NovaServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class NovaServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected function registerRoutes()
    {
        parent::registerRoutes();

        Route::prefix('nova-api')
            ->middleware(['nova'])
            ->domain(config('nova.domain'))
            ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Nova')
            ->group(base_path('routes/nova-api.php'));

    }
}
```